# Name of Exception corresponding to "No such file or directory"?

Tags: python, bash, subprocess, try-catch, python-3.10

I would like to ask if there is an exception name in `try: except:` for the error `No such file or directory`.

For example:

```py
try:
    subprocess.run(["bash", my_path + "start.sh"], shell=False)
except NoDirectory:
    print('Error: This directory was not found. Please make sure the path is correct')
```

Or is there a way to get an error code from `subprocess.run` and to check it from there?

Comment: Are you looking for `FileNotFoundError`?

Comment: That might be a solution

Comment: You'll only get `FileNotFoundError` if the command itself is not found (`bash` in this case.)  I think your best solution is to check the return status of the command, and if it was unsuccessful, look for "No such file or directory" in the command's error output.

Comment: Can't you just run it without the `try`/`except` and see what it says the exception is?

Comment: No, as @JohnGordon stated, `bash` will throw the error, not `subprocess`. It will never make it to the `expect`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `stderr=subprocess.PIPE` argument so you can examine the error output.

```
import subprocess

r = subprocess.run(['bash', '/some/nonexistent/path.sh'], stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

if r.returncode:
    if b'No such file or directory' in r.stderr:
        print('That file was not found.')
```

Answer (score 1):

I could not catch the `bash` exception in your code, as it is written. But you can try the following code, even if it's longer. You can also send a tuple of commands, instead of one command at a time:

> **NOTE** - Tested on Ubuntu 20.04, using Python 3.8

```
commands = ("bash start.sh", "date",)
for c in commands:
    p = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(c), stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                         stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    output, error = p.communicate()
    rc = p.returncode
    if rc != 0:
        if error.find(b"No such file or directory"):
            print("Error: This directory was not found. Please make sure the path is correct")
        else:
            print(error.decode().strip())
    else:
        print(output.decode().strip())
```

**Output:**

```
Error: This directory was not found. Please make sure the path is correct
Wed 29 Dec 2021 06:10:15 PM EST
```

Very interested if someone figures out how to catch the `No such file or directory` from `bash` using `subprocess`.